# Swift TableViewCell from Array to JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I have it the table returning the data from a fixed Array in the swift code.

now however I want to switch that fixed data out for the data in this JSON - https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news

However because I have used the keyword news in the current code, I am finding it hard to call this JSON as I need to use the keyword news as the JSONP has

> {"news":...}

Now this is the current code that I know all need to change this to inject the JSON data.

```
func createArray() -> [News] {

   return [News(title: "Hello") , News(title: "how") , News(title: "You")]  
}
```

At first I thought it would be as simple as changing my nowplaying json fetch data.

This is the script (struct parts not included in this):

```
@objc func nowplaying(){
    let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/station/playing"
    guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err) in

    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
       let nowplaying = try JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data)
        nowplaying.data.forEach {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.artist.text = nowplaying.data.first?.track.artist
             self.song.text = nowplaying.data.first?.track.title
             }
           }
      } catch let jsonErr {
         print("error json ", jsonErr)
    }
  }.resume()
}
```

how would I do it using the following code

```
struct NewsData: Decodable{
    let news: [articalData]
}

struct articalData: Decodeable{
    let title: String
}
```

Fetch news:

```
   @objc func newsfetch(){
        let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news"
        guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return }


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err) in

    guard let news = data else { return }
    do {
        let news = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: news)
           NewsData.news.forEach {
             print(NewsData.news.title)
           }
       } catch let jsonErr{
            print("error json ", jsonErr)
       }
 }.resume()
}
```

however when I do I am getting errors

the first 1 is coming in the very first Struct

> struct NewsData: Decodable{ // the error Type 'NewsData' does not
>   conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Second error

> struct articalData: Decodeable{ // Use of undeclared type
>   'Decodeable'

Third error

> NewsData.news.forEach { // Contextual type for closure argument list
>   expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored insert '_ in'
>   // Instance member 'news' cannot be used on type 'NewsData'
>
> print(NewsData.news.title) //   Instance member 'news' cannot be used on type 'NewsData' & Value of type '[articalData]' has no member 'title'
>   }

I know that what I am trying to achieve is different from my nowplaying JSON but they are formatted very much the same way. Any advice would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and second error are caused by a typo (already mentioned in Marina's answer).

It's twice `Decodable`. And please name structs with starting capital letter

```
struct NewsData: Decodable {
    let news: [ArticleData]
}

struct ArticleData: Decodable {
    let title: String
}
```

---

The third error are actually two errors. You have to call `forEach` on the instance `news` (not on the type `News`) and you have to use the parameter in the closure.

I renamed a few variables to avoid confusion

```
guard let data = data else { return }
do {
    let newsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: data)
    newsData.news.forEach { item in
         print(item.title)                           
    }
```

or shorter with the *Shorthand Argument Name* syntax

```
newsData.news.forEach { print($0.title) }
```

Please **read** error messages. Most of them are very clear and descriptive.

Comment: getting this error now - Value of type 'NewsData' has no member 'forEach' trying both news.forEach { item in
                                    print(item.title)
                               } and the shortcode

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo on your struct type, explained on your second error:

> struct articalData: Decodeable{ // Use of undeclared type 'Decodeable'

This should be:

```
struct NewsData: Decodable{
    let news: [articalData]
}

struct articalData: Decodable{
    let title: String
}
```